# Is there a better way to write this SQL query in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a stored procedure with the following query.  Based on the @range parameter I am adding more conditions to the where clause.  The query below is giving me the correct results.  I was wondering if I can avoid repeating the previous "Idx", "IdxType" as the range increases.  Is there a better way to write this query?

```
 SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM 
        MyTable
    WHERE
    ID1 = @Id1
    and Id1Type = @Id1Type
    and 
    (
        (@range = 2 and ID2 = @Id2 and ID2Type = @Id2Type)
         or
        (@range = 3 and ID2 = @Id2 and ID2Type = @Id2Type 
            and ID3 = @Id3 and ID3Type = @Id3Type)
        or
        (@range = 4 and ID2 = Id2 and ID2Type = @Id2Type 
          and ID3 = @Id3 and ID3Type = @Id3Type
          and ID4 = @Id4 and ID4Type = @Id4Type)
        or
        (@range = 5 and ID2 = @Id2 and ID2Type = @Id2Type 
          and ID3 = @Id3 and ID3Type = @Id3Type
          and ID4 = @Id4 and ID4Type = @Id4Type
           and ID5 = @Id5 and ID5Type = @Id5Type)
    )
```

Comment: To be honest you already turned the wrong way when decided to store separate `ID1`, `ID2`, etc columns. Relational databases are designed for a different data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to regroup terms atleast using simple boolean logic

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM 
    MyTable
  WHERE
    ID1 = @Id1 and Id1Type = @Id1Type and
    (@range < 2 or ID2 = @Id2 and ID2Type = @Id2Type) and 
    (@range < 3 or ID3 = @Id3 and ID3Type = @Id3Type) and
    (@range < 4 or ID4 = @Id4 and ID4Type = @Id4Type) and
    (@range < 5 or ID5 = @Id5 and ID5Type = @Id5Type)
```